# How do I reduce the +- symbols on American voltage sources with the bipole length reduced?

Tags: circuitikz

I can reduce the bipole length, but the +/- signs on American voltage sources don't get smaller. How can I reduce those also?

```
\documentclass[border=1.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, font=\sffamily, 
  smallckt/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.9cm},
  ssmallckt/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm},
  sssmallckt/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm}
]

\draw (0,0) to [V, invert] (0,2);
\draw (1,0) to [V, invert, smallckt] (1,2);
\draw (2,0) to [V, invert, ssmallckt] (2,2);
\draw (3,0) to [V, invert, sssmallckt] (3,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the key `inner plus` and `inner minus` inside `bipoles/vsourceam`

```
\documentclass[border=1.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, font=\sffamily, 
    smallckt/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.9cm},
           circuitikz/bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus ={\scriptsize $+$},
           circuitikz/bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus ={\scriptsize $-$},
    ssmallckt/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm,
           circuitikz/bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus ={\tiny $+$},
           circuitikz/bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus ={\tiny $-$}},
    sssmallckt/.style={circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm,
           circuitikz/bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus ={\tiny $+$},
           circuitikz/bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus ={\tiny $-$}}
    ]
        \draw (0,0) to [V, invert] (0,2);
        \draw (1,0) to [V, invert, smallckt] (1,2);
        \draw (2,0) to [V, invert, ssmallckt] (2,2);
        \draw (3,0) to [V, invert, sssmallckt] (3,2);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]